# How to Login with OTP, in Laravel Passport OAuth2 authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel Passport OAuth2 for login authentication. And its working perfectly with Username and password authentication. But I want to authenticate with OTP based login,and I have didn't find any suitable documentations.
I Have tried following link. :

```
https://medium.com/@arifulislam_ron/create-custom-grant-token-in-laravel-passport-1ff0cc255dc5
```

#### My AuthServiceProvider Code:

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use App\Auth\Grants\OtpGrant;
use App\Passport\Bridge\RefereshTokenRepository;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
Use League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer


#### Boot: 
 $this->registerPolicies();
        app(AuthorizationServer::class)->enableGrantType(
            $this->makeOtpGrant(), Passport::tokensExpireIn()
        );

#### Function: 
protected function makeOtpGrant()
    {
        $grant = new otpGrant(
            $this->app->make(RefreshTokenRepository::class)
        );
        $grant->setRefreshTokenTTL(Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn());
        return $grant;
    }
```

#### My App\Auth\Grants\OtpGran Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth\Grants;

use RuntimeException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Exceptions\OtpException;
use Laravel\Passport\Bridge\User;
use League\OAuth2\Server\RequestEvent;
use App\Http\sapi\Grants\OtpVerifierFactory;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\AbstractGrant;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Entities\UserEntityInterface;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Entities\ClientEntityInterface;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\ResponseTypes\ResponseTypeInterface;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\RefreshTokenRepositoryInterface;

class OtpGrant extends AbstractGrant
{
    /**
     * @param RefreshTokenRepositoryInterface $refreshTokenRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        RefreshTokenRepositoryInterface $refreshTokenRepository
    ) {
        $this->setRefreshTokenRepository($refreshTokenRepository);

        $this->refreshTokenTTL = new \DateInterval('P1M');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function respondToAccessTokenRequest(
        ServerRequestInterface $request,
        ResponseTypeInterface $responseType,
        \DateInterval $accessTokenTTL
    ) {
        // Validate request
        $client = $this->validateClient($request);
        $scopes = $this->validateScopes($this->getRequestParameter('scope', $request));
        $user = $this->validateUser($request, $client);

        // Finalize the requested scopes
        $scopes = $this->scopeRepository->finalizeScopes($scopes, $this->getIdentifier(), $client, $user->getIdentifier());

        // Issue and persist new tokens
        $accessToken = $this->issueAccessToken($accessTokenTTL, $client, $user->getIdentifier(), $scopes);
        $refreshToken = $this->issueRefreshToken($accessToken);

        // Inject tokens into response
        $responseType->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        $responseType->setRefreshToken($refreshToken);

        return $responseType;
    }

    protected function validateUser(ServerRequestInterface $request, ClientEntityInterface $client)
    {
        $otp = $this->getRequestParameter('otp', $request);
        if (is_null($otp)) {
            throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('otp');
        }

        $otpVerifierParam = $this->getRequestParameter('otp_verifier', $request);

        $otpVerifier = OtpVerifierFactory::getOtpVerifier(
                            $this->getRequestParameter('otp_verifier', $request, 'BL_INTERNAL')
                        );

        if ( is_null($otpVerifier) ) {
            throw OtpException::invalidOtpVerifier();
        }

        $isValidOtp = $otpVerifier->verify($otp);

        if (!$isValidOtp){
            throw OtpException::invalidOtp();
        }

        $username = $this->getRequestParameter('username', $request);
        if (is_null($username)) {
            throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('username');
        }

        $user = $this->getUserEntityByUserOtp(
            $username,
            $this->getIdentifier(),
            $client
        );

        if ($user instanceof UserEntityInterface === false) {
            $this->getEmitter()->emit(new RequestEvent(RequestEvent::USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, $request));

            throw OAuthServerException::invalidCredentials();
        }

        return $user;
    }

    private function getUserEntityByUserOtp($username, $grantType, ClientEntityInterface $clientEntity)
    {
        $provider = config('auth.guards.api.provider');

        if (is_null($model = config('auth.providers.'.$provider.'.model'))) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Unable to determine authentication model from configuration.');
        }

        $user = (new $model)->where('username', $username)->first();

        if (is_null($user)) {
            return;
        }

        return new User($user->getAuthIdentifier());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getIdentifier()
    {
        return 'otp_grant';
    } 

    }
```

#### Output coming like:

```
{
    "message": "Target class [App\\Providers\\RefreshTokenRepository] does not exist.",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\onesapi\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php",
    "line": 805,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\onesapi\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php",
            "line": 681,
            "function": "build",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

After using this code getting same issue for all authentication apis

### Expected Output is:

```
{
    "token": {
        "token_type": "Bearer",
        "expires_in": 10367998,
        "access_token": "__ Access Token Key",
        "refresh_token": "__ Refresh token key"
    },
```

If any one has Idea about OTP based login authentication please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

the error says

> "Target class [App\Providers\RefreshTokenRepository] does not exist."

It is because in your AuthServiceProvider file you have a misspelling.
Try to replace
**use App\Passport\Bridge\RefereshTokenRepository;**
with
**use App\Passport\Bridge\RefreshTokenRepository;**

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the answer of your question but this is a suggestion.

for this to work, consider changing your validateUser function in your OtpGrant class.
OtpGrant class is responsible for validating User and generating token. So in validateUser function try removing

```
 $otp = $this->getRequestParameter('otp', $request);
    if (is_null($otp)) {
        throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('otp');
    }

    $otpVerifierParam = $this->getRequestParameter('otp_verifier', $request);

    $otpVerifier = OtpVerifierFactory::getOtpVerifier(
                        $this->getRequestParameter('otp_verifier', $request, 'BL_INTERNAL')
                    );

    if ( is_null($otpVerifier) ) {
        throw OtpException::invalidOtpVerifier();
    }

    $isValidOtp = $otpVerifier->verify($otp);

    if (!$isValidOtp){
        throw OtpException::invalidOtp();
    }
```

this code and implement your own version of otp generation and authentication.(in fact this is the part where you can implement any sort of user validation and authentication.)

also for your help, OtpGrant::getIdentifier() is the function which gives your grant a name.

Rest can be left as it is. This will work just fine.